# Don't syntax highlight my non-code

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, editor

Quite simple actually. I saw an answer, that desperately screamed for a little formatting as codeblock (quoting JavaDoc), and decided: "Why not suggest an edit?"

Imagine how flabberghasted I was when I realized I can't stop code-prettify:

[image: highlights everywhere]

for the record: I also tried `<!-- language: none -->` but to no avail.

Is it just the preview, or are we not getting `class="nocode"` anymore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a *newline* between the paragraph and the comment.

```
You need to call close() method on your MessageProducer. As per the Java docs:-

<!-- language: lang-none -->

    void close()
```

renders as:

> You need to call close() method on your MessageProducer. As per the Java docs:-
>
> ```
> void close()
> ```

For documentation quotes, I'd not use a code block; I'd use `>` block quotes instead, however.

I've edited [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25306960/100297) now to read:

```
You need to call [`close()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#close()) on your `MessageProducer`. As per the Java docs:-

>     void close()  
>                throws JMSException
>
> Closes the message producer.
>   
> Since a provider may allocate some resources on behalf of a `MessageProducer` outside the Java virtual machine, clients should close them when they are not needed. Relying on garbage collection to eventually reclaim these resources may not be timely enough.
```

which formats as:

---

You need to call [`close()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#close()) on your `MessageProducer`. As per the Java docs:-

> ```
> void close()  
>            throws JMSException
> ```
>
> Closes the message producer.
>
> Since a provider may allocate some resources on behalf of a `MessageProducer` outside the Java virtual machine, clients should close them when they are not needed. Relying on garbage collection to eventually reclaim these resources may not be timely enough.

---

I corrected the documentation quote (it was badly copied), added correct attribution by linking and formatted the `throws` line to match the documentation indentation.

Now the method signature is even correctly highlighted.

Comment: This should be a blockquote, not a codeblock at all.

Comment: @Joe: sure, I was addressing *that too*; but you do need to answer the initial problem **as well**.

Comment: @Vogel612: That indentation doesn't actually add anything here, does it?

Comment: @Vogel612: ah! I see where that missing word went. I'll correct.

Comment: @Vogel612: your suggested edit was indeed auto-rejected as it conflicted with an edit I made.